# Dataframe is not updated when columns are passed to function using apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have two dataframes like this:

```
   A   B
a  1  10
b  2  11
c  3  12
d  4  13 

   A   B
a  11 NaN
b NaN NaN
c NaN  20
d  16  30
```

They have identical column names and indices. My goal is to replace the `NAs` in `df2` by the values of `df1`. Currently, I do this like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(1, 5), 'B': range(10, 14)}, index=list('abcd'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [11, np.nan, np.nan, 16], 'B': [np.nan, np.nan, 20, 30]}, index=list('abcd'))    

def repl_na(s, d):

    s[s.isnull().values] = d[s.isnull().values][s.name]

    return s    

df2.apply(repl_na, args=(df1, ))
```

which gives me the desired output:

```
    A   B
a  11  10
b   2  11
c   3  20
d  16  30
```

My question is now how this could be accomplished if the indices of the dataframes are different (column names are still the same, and the columns have the same length). So I would have a `df2` like this(`df1` is unchanged):

```
    A   B
0  11 NaN
1 NaN NaN
2 NaN  20
3  16  30
```

Then the above code does not work anymore since the indices of the dataframes are different. Could someone tell me how the line

```
s[s.isnull().values] = d[s.isnull().values][s.name]
```

has to be modified in order to get the same result as above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could temporarily change the indexes on `df1` to be the same as `df2`and just [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) with `df2`;

```
df2.combine_first(df1.set_index(df2.index))

    A   B
1  11  10
2   2  11
3   3  20
4  16  30
```

Comment: That's great! Even avoids the `apply`. I upvote it for now and might accept it later on depending on the other answers' quality.

Comment: Could ayou also explain why my attempt fails and how it has to be modified to make it work?!

Comment: @Cleb Sadly, I'm more of a beginner in pandas, so I'm not sure I can give a correct explanation of why your existing code breaks. If that's what you need, someone else may have to go into that analysis.

Comment: Ok. Your code gets the job done for this particular problem. Maybe I will ask a follow-up question asking specifically about this problem.